# How do kill count achievements work in multiplayer?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I was looking at my achievement list and saw lots of achievements for kills, like The Elitist achievement.

[image]

How does this work in multiplayer? Will a kill count towards my achievement progress if my ally gets the killing blow, or only if I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works the same as experience.  It doesn't matter who delivers the killing blow, you just have to be in the vicinity.